# Class to Instance Registry Typing in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use classes as input values to a registry method where the return value is a cached instance of that instance.  However I do not find a way to make this type safe.

What I want is something like this:

```
class MyRegistry {
  getInstance<T, C extends Class<T>>(cls: C): T;
}

let x: MyThing = registry.getInstance(MyThing);
```

Is there a way to make this work? I'm aware there are ways to type out newables but I cannot find a way to make the return value concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter type should describe constructor of the Class you are passing as a param. This can be achieved using the generic interface:

```js
interface Class<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

class MyRegistry {
  getInstance<T>(param: Class<T>): T {
    // do your magic
  }
}
```

You can see it in work [here](https://codepen.io/meeroslav/pen/pxroJK).

In case you need to use subclass C, that is of course easily extendable with:

```js
class MyRegistry {
  getInstance<T, C extends T>(param: Class<C>): T {
    // do your magic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a constructor signature to make the compiler extract the instance type from the constructor:

```
class MyRegistry {
    getInstance<T>(cls: new (...args: any[])=> T): T {
        return null as any;
    }
}

class MyThing { private x: number }

let registry = new MyRegistry();
let x = registry.getInstance(MyThing); // inffered as MyThing
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [something like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDCkawN4F9RLo6UCasApgB4AuhAdgCbZaoaa6wCyAngEqEDmAllKQCdWAHgAqRMpRqxSrAA6EA9gDMEWAHypgsWAGIB3WAF5YFQgHcWEOWIA0sAJIV+ECiEKj5hMevUAKAEptWC5CUicXN28AVQlyajhRf3AoAC5YaIDUWANSAFcBChkACz4AOn1uMtDSPxSs6EdnUld3TwVhaM0MBhBFZpzjUwsWDm4+QVZA0H7+WGIhgWqwiJaovxwYLIB6bfn0zagZgdZF5fDm1sINrDwdvdYD2+BgIA):

```
class Class {}
class ClassY extends Class {}

class MyRegistry<T extends typeof Class> {
  #reg = new Map<T, InstanceType<T>>()
  getInstance<U extends T>(cls: U) { return this.#reg.get(cls) as InstanceType<U> }
  setInstance(u: InstanceType<T>) { this.#reg.set(u.constructor as T, u) }
}

const r = new MyRegistry()
const x = r.getInstance(Class) // x: Class
const y = r.getInstance(ClassY) // y: ClassY
```